# Errors compiling MinGW for CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, build-error

after making a breakthrough with my earlier MiniGW problem i have come across another. This is very diffrent from my understanding. from what i see everything compiles ok and i dont have a good enough understanding of cmake to know what the problem is.

here is the Error log

```
||=== Build: Icarus in Icarus (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
CMakeFiles\Makefile2|60|recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/all' failed|
CMakeFiles\Makefile2|72|recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/rule' failed|
D:\Projects\SVN\Icarus\build\Makefile|110|recipe for target 'Icarus' failed|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Here is the line in the makefile it points to

```
# Build rule for target.
Icarus: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Icarus
.PHONY : Icarus
```

And here is the first section it points to in makefile2

```
CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/all:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/depend
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/build
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_report D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build/CMakeFiles  
    @echo "Built target Icarus"
.PHONY : CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/all
```

And finally here is the final section

```
# Build rule for subdir invocation for target.
CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/rule: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build/CMakeFiles 31
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/rule
```

hopefully this is enough information to fix the error.

---

Edit information from about the error

```
Running command: c:/MinGW/bin/make.exe -f "D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build/Makefile"  VERBOSE=1 Icarus
"c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -HD:/Projects/SVN/Icarus -BD:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
c:/MinGW/bin/make.exe -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Icarus
make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build'
"c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -HD:/Projects/SVN/Icarus -BD:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
"c:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build/CMakeFiles 31
c:/MinGW/bin/make.exe -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/all
make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build'
c:/MinGW/bin/make.exe -f CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Icarus.dir/depend
make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" D:\Projects\SVN\Icarus D:\Projects\SVN\Icarus D:\Projects\SVN\Icarus\build D:\Projects\SVN\Icarus\build D:\Projects\SVN\Icarus\build\CMakeFiles\Icarus.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
make.exe[3]: Leaving directory 'D:/Projects/SVN/Icarus/build'
```

Comment: ***hopefully this is enough information to fix the error.*** I say doubtful. The error message is that the recipe for target XXX failed but did not give a clue why.

Comment: @drescherjm its the best it would give me

Comment: Isn't there anything above this in the error log?

Comment: @drescherjm edited it into the post

Comment: Still nothing that helps identify the problem. Maybe someone who uses this library has had this issue.

Comment: @drescherjm this is all the information i am given upon compiling the project. this error happens nomatter what MiniGW platform i use.

Comment: Are you really using MiniGW or MinGW? The posted Makefiles do not help at all, you can remove them. The CMakeLists.txt are usually helpful, though. You have to add the compiler / linker error. Until you provide this piece of information we cannot help you.